# Trying to use a pd.df column value to replace a string value in the same row, seperate column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop

I have tried to use .iat but that is a static value.  I have about 75 rows with two columns, I'm looking to replace a hyperlink in column "B" with the domain from column "A".  I think .iat would be the best way but I can't figure out the dynamic value for (current row, 1).

Let me explain a bit more, because the answers below are a little too simplistic for what I'm asking....

I want to replace the tag {URL} in Column B with the different unique values of each corresponding row within Column A.

```
df['Column A'] = ('xyz.com', 'abc.com')
df['Column B'] = https://thisone.com/xxx/x?{URL}/xxx/xxx
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to replace just one specific column B value, then try use `np.where`:

```
import numpy as np

value_to_replace = "whatever"

# This is saying if B == value_to_replace, set column B to A, else just leave as B
# result       = np.where((conditional),                        value if true,  value if false) 
df["Column B"] = np.where((df["Column B"] == value_to_replace), df["Column A"], df["Column B"])

# extension of above where if B == value_to_replace, set B to first 2 characters of B + all of A, else leave as B:
df["Column B"] = np.where((df["Column B"] == value_to_replace), df["Column B"].str[:2] +df["Column A"], df["Column B"])
```

If you want the replacement to apply to every row, it's simpler:

```
# this just sets column B to column A
df["Column B"] = df["Column A"]

# this sets column B to the first 2 characters of column B + all of column A
df["Column B"] = df["Column B"].str[:2] + df["Column A"]
```

Just substitute the `first 2 characters of B + all of A` bit for either method with whatever string operation you need to do to replace the hyperlinks.

Comment: nice explanations! you can also use the more concise `df.where()` when one of the conditions is no-op, e.g.: `df["Column B"] = df["Column B"].where(df["Column B"].ne(value_to_replace), df["Column A"])`

Comment: Thanks! And yes that look much neater

Comment: Thank you both for the explanation and cmds.  Using .dfwhere( ) I got a boolean array expected error for the condition, not object.

Comment: So the answers was to go df['B'] = "https://xzy.com/d/d/d" + df["A"] + "dxkdem"